# The best storage choice for iPhone navigation based application?

Tags: ios, iphone, data-storage

I'm confused about what would be the best data storage (plists, SQLite, Core Data etc.) for my iPhone app that is navigation based and has all kinds of lists and info. I'm very new to this and the multiple types get me confused.

For example, first view is a table view for type of recipe (Ex. Cookie Recipes), second view is also a table view for all kinds of cookie recipes (Ex. Chocolate Cookies), third view would be the recipe for the Chocolate Cookie (numbers, text etc. stored).

It would be a non-static app, that would make the USER create the table cell "Cookie Recipes" and then create the "Chocolate Cookies" and also input the info for the chocolate cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property lists are very handy when you have static data.  There's a structured editor built right into Xcode and they show up in code as instances of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.  But they aren't really designed for managing changing data, they are just a serialisation format.

If the user is editing complex data, you're better off using Core Data or SQLite.  Core Data is a higher level interface designed to be used with Cocoa.  SQLite would do the job as well, but I'd probably suggest only using that if you are already familiar with it.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use SQLite instead of CoreData. Yes, CoreData comes with a fancy data modeling tool but it also comes with a huge amount of weird quirks when it comes to using Xcode4 as well as ancient issues on the simulator.